# Command to find user who runs the server(IIS)?

Tags: python

I hosted my django project in IIS on windows,Is there any python function to find the user who runs IIS?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIS App Pools control (run)  your Python applications

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the user account in which IIS is executed you can try:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
"salem" # my username account
```